# On the definition of Injective function.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, definition

Let $f$ be a function whose domain is a set $X$. The function $f$ is said to be injective provided that for all $a$ and $b$ in $X$ if $f ( a ) = f ( b )$ , then $a=b$; that is, $f ( a ) = f ( b )$ implies $a = b$. Equivalently, if $a \ne b$ then $f ( a ) \ne f ( b )$  in the contrapositive statement.

Symbolically,
$$\forall a , b \in X , f ( a ) = f ( b ) \implies a = b ,$$

which is logically equivalent to the contrapositive,
$$\forall a , b \in X , a \ne b \implies f ( a ) ≠ f ( b ) .$$

> **Question.** If I prove that $$f(a)\ne f(b)\implies a\ne b$$ can I conclude that $f$ is injective?

Comment: No. That implication is true for all functions, and it means that every value from its domain gets mapped to exactly one value in the co-domain.

Comment: Can you think of a Single function where the Implication is not true ? that is : $f(a) \not = f(b)$ , yet $a=b$ ? Does that make sense ?

Comment: Fix doesn't refer to the same implication as yours; he meant : $(f(a) \neq f(b) \Rightarrow a \neq b) \nRightarrow f$ is injective.

Comment: Every function satisfies you last expression, so no.

Comment: I prefer to think of injectivity to mean the preimage of a singleton in the function's range is a singleton.

Comment: Not sure whether your Comment was for me , @Abezhiko , but I assume it was for me. My Implication is Exactly what OP is talking about & I am trying to make OP see that (1) Even before checking for Injectivity , we must try to get some Example functions which will not satisfy the Criteria (2) We can get no Such Example functions , because all functions will satisfy the given Criteria (3) When all functions satisfy the given Criteria , even Non-Injective functions will satisfy the Criteria , hence that is false.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work; a counterexample is given by $f(x) = \tan(x)$. Even if $f(a) \neq f(b) \implies a \neq b$, it is not an injective function, since it is $\pi$-periodic and thus an infinite number of points have the same image. You can convince yourself by looking at its graph.